# Temporary loss of all references

Tags: biblatex, compiling

I am sorry that this question might end to be not perfectly structured, but I have a very confusing problem and have no idea how to get closer to a solution.

I am writing my thesis using biblatex for citations. Mostly everything runs fine, but now it is the 7th or 8th time that no citations are found anymore. This happens without changing anything in the code or the settings or the bib file and it takes often more than a week before the citations are back out of nothing. (And I build the document in the meantime 10 or 20 times and so far I did not manage to just save it more often to get the citations back earlier.)

Now I am coming closer to the date were I want to hand in the thesis and have no idea what to do in case this happens also in the final week.

I am using atom as an editor but also generated the document using the command line.

When running pdflatex I receive the expected warning

```
Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                main
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards."
```

And running biber results in

```
INFO - This is Biber 2.16
INFO - Logfile is 'main.blg'
INFO - Reading 'main.bcf'
INFO - Found 0 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Found 2 citekeys in bib section 1
INFO - Found 0 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Found 11 citekeys in bib section 2
INFO - Found 0 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Found 2 citekeys in bib section 3
INFO - Found 198 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'Bibliography.bib' for section 0
INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'Bibliography.bib'
```

But running pdflatex afterwards does not change anything.

Another experiment I started was to run a minimal example of citations and this also fails. I would expect that I have some general problems with my system but I am very confused as those problems come and go without me doing anything.

I would really welcome every hint, that might help to solve this issue.

Best
Mareike

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that shows the problem.

Comment: if the log stops like this it normally means that the biber cache has been corrupted. Run on a command line `biber --cache` and then delete the file it reports. The next compilation will then unpack biber again (this can take a bit time).

Comment: Thanks a lot @UlrikeFischer this solved the issue. Still did not get why it solved itself after a while. But I am much more relaxed now as I now that I can actively solve the problem!!

Comment: Years ago one had to delete the biber cache rather often, but it is now quite stable, so it is probably some local problem. Perhaps something in your computer cleans up the tmp folder sometimes (or blocks it while doing some virus checking).

Comment: While the cache issue has sporadically appeared for people for a variety of reasons for many years, in recent years the problems seem to have mainly been focussed on Mac OS systems. Maybe there is a cleanup job there that causes issues - or the file permissions settings play up.